# passing back answers in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

i have this code than runs perfectly .. returns a true .. when tracing the values are ok .. but its not returning back the answer .. it acts strangely when it ends and always return empty list .. uninstantiated variable ..

```
 createNewList(Capacity,RemainingNumbers,Bins,ExtendedBins).



createNewList(0,Bins,Bins,ExtendedBins,ExtendedBins).
createNewList(_,[],_,ExtendedBins,ExtendedBins).
createNewList(Capacity,[Element|Rest],Bins,Temp,ExtendedBins) :-
 .
 .
 .
 .
  createNewList(Capacity,Rest,Bins,NewList,Result).
```

Greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ive found the error .. i was sending the value that i want to have the answer in instaniated as an empty list .. so i always got the answer back as empty .. fixed that ..